# UIBarButtonItem is blue instead of image

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

Here is what I have in my viewDidLoad method:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back")
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "back")
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

I am trying to have a custom icon image for my back button in my navigation controller. Instead of the image showing in it's original format, I am seeing the image in blue. **How do I get the image to show properly?**

Comment: Try with rendering mode: `UIImage(named: "back")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)`

Comment: This works!!!!!!!! :) Can you please add this as an answer so I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `renderingMode` for your custom image with `AlwaysOriginal` mode. See below code for solved it.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "back")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Quickest solution

```
.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Or you can create custom barButton item, with custom view

Answer (score 0):

Set the tintColor property of the barbuttonItem.

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.tintColor = "any color"
```